# PostgreSQL, query two (or more) tables without using a secondary key

Tags: postgresql

I have such situation:

> Table1: pk1 int, pk2 int, string1, string2, string3
>     Table2: pk3 int, string4, string5, string6

Where pk2 int from first table is a same like pk3 (index) from second table.
When creating tables I was not use secondary key and now I have to query those two tables in single query if possible.
Till now I do this with two queries:

```
SELECT pk1, pk2, string1, string2, string3 
FROM table1 
WHERE string1 ILIKE 'a%'
```

and then, loop through results:

```
SELECT pk3, string4, string5, string6 
from table2 WHERE pk3=" & Cint(reader.GetValue(1))
```

Note: reader.GetValue(1) = pk2 from first table)

Finally I get needed local results like:

```
1, string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6
```

I simplified a bit with using of ANY or IN in second query but I belive that powerful data system like is PostgreSQL can do this in a single query.

How that query should look like on showed example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.pk1, 
       t1.pk2, 
       t1.string1, 
       t1.string2, 
       t1.string3, 
       t2.string4, 
       t2.string5, 
       t2.string6
FROM table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.pk2 = t2.pk3
WHERE t1.string1 ILIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: Hi "name", JOIN is what I search for? Didn't try yet because my tables have many columns. But I wonder from where do you take (never defined) t1 and t2 variables and are they absolutely necessary in such situation?

Comment: @user973238 those are aliases for the table names. They are not strictly necessary, but make the query easier to read (and require less typing) See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Comment: My query works as expected! :) I have to read a bit on this very useful function. Thank you very much again "name". I noted that with "alias names" I can mix t1 and t2 variables to make it more suitable for my dataadapter and datagrid what is extra nice possibility!

Answer (score 1):

Use [join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html) clause to combine two tables and get the result.